# Java FileOutputStream returning 0 size files

Tags: java, url, while-loop, download, fileoutputstream

I've put together a program that takes in a specific URL then scans for a specific directory named after a time and date so for example, say the url fed is 'www.url.com', it will scan for this directory 'www.url.com/date&time'.

The link is constantly updating and at random times the link will be removed and overwritten with a new one, and it is my objective to scan the url download the directory then scan again for a new directory to be made replacing the old one and download the new file again.

```
while(numberofDownloads > 0){

        linkname = urlprint(url);//finds name of link (essentically the top half of the code in urldownload)

        if(!linknameTemp.equals(linkname)){
            numberofDownloads--;
            print("downloads left: " + numberofDownloads);
            linkname = urlprint(url);
            linknameTemp = linkname;
            urldownload(url);
        }

    }
```

And this is the function I am calling during the while loop when it detects a change in the url directories, works the first time then the file downloads with 0 bytes after the first.

```
    private static String urldownload(String url) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    String linkname = "";

    for (Element link : links) {

        String templinkname = trim(link.text(), 35);

        if(Character.isDigit(templinkname.charAt(0))){
            linkname = trim(link.text(), 35);
        }    

        //String linkname = trim(link.text(), 35);
    }

    String urlZip = (url + linkname + "urilist.zip");//file is always named urilist.zip

    URL urldownload = new URL(urlZip);

    print(linkname);

    linkname = linkname.substring(0,linkname.length()-1); //remove last character '/' character to not confuse fileoutputstream
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(urldownload.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(linkname+".zip");//rename file after directory
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

    return null;
}
```

So when I run the code the first file it downloads is perfectly fine, however the next files (however many I value 'numberofDownloads') all download to my project directory but at 0 bytes.

How can I modify the code to allow me to check for updates to the directory then download the file inside however many times I need and without error?

Comment: You need to call close() either on FileOutputStream or the channel.

Comment: I've added 'fos.close();' at the end of urldownload before the null, but now I'm getting files half the size and damaged, where am I supposed to call it or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Then you should use close on the channel.

Comment: I've tried closing both, and its working, but at random times the files are corrupt, is there a better practice I could be using with fileoutputstream with some try and catch clause?

Comment: try{
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(urldownload.openStream());
        
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(linkname+".zip");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);                
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fos.close();
            rbc.close();
this is what I'm using, it works about 75% of the time, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if **ZipOutputStream** class instead of **FileOutputStream** can help you resolve half and corrupted files ?

Comment: what is ZipOutputStream? from what I see users are using it to create zip files not download them